# make a loop to generate dataframe nested in a list loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a loop that connects to an API to get data and put it in a list that I convert to a dataframe. The loop repeats as many times as there is a `Ticker`, which is a list of company names.

```
**d = []**
for symbol in stocks['Ticker'][:5]:
        for symbol in stocks['Ticker'][:5]:
            api_url = f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbol}/chart/ytd?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}&chartCloseOnly=true'
            data_chart = requests.get(api_url).json()
            data_chart= pd.DataFrame(list(data_chart)).assign(Ticker=symbol)
          **d.append(data_chart)**

**pd.DataFrame(d)**
```

This is a history of the share price of a hundred companies over several years. That is to say that for the company `AA` it will take out the price of the last years and then start again the loop and the data to put that of the company following `APPLE` for example.

What I'm trying to do to avoid that at each iteration the table is overwritten I would like to nest it in a bigger loop that would store each time in a new dataframe the table of `AA` then `AAPL` etc.  These problematic lines are indicated with stars.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you're asking for, but it seems like:

- `d` is a list of 'data_chart's (DataFrame).
- Each 'data_chart' is a DataFrame for a particular ticker symbol that is stored from a request as a json object.

It seems like you should be using dictionaries to store you data charts, so you can access them by ticker. Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from typing import Dict

import json # to convert the json object into a dictionary  

IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN: str # assuming we have this

data_charts: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame] = {}
for symbol in stocks['Ticker'][:5]:
        for symbol in stocks['Ticker'][:5]:
            api_url = f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbol}/chart/ytd?token={IEX_CLOUD_API_TOKEN}&chartCloseOnly=true'
            data_chart: dict = requests.get(api_url).json()
            data_charts[symbol] = pd.DataFrame(data_chart)
print(data_charts)
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was not very clear and the editing was done after ! It seems that the loop would be more efficient to make a dictionary first and that I transform in dataframe! 
Besides, I didn't understand the usefulness of putting in brackets the .json step in loads.json()?                                                                                                    `data_chart: dict = json.loads(requests.get(api_url).json())                                                                                                               data_chart: dict = requests.get(api_url).json()`